# Nginx: How do I pass Origin header through proxy?

Tags: nginx

Currently I have a service setup at `https://example.com` that, as part of its standard logging setup, logs the request origin. This is a public data API, it's open to any and every origin.

This service used to be at `https://example_2.com`, but I proxy that address to the new to ensure non-breaking service for everyone else. This is done in the following way:

```
server {
    ...

    server_name example_2.com;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://example.com;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `Origin` header turns up as `null` at the proxy destination. I need the header to arrive intact so I can know where the request came from.

I tried adding `proxy_pass_request_headers` but that seemingly does nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't fixed passing `Origin` through, I did learn that Nginx automatically populates `Referer` which will work for my purpose. It's not great, and I'd love to know how to get a non-null `Origin`, but I thought I'd post this as it might help others who similarly can get away with this as a "solution".